# Copying values not formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code, which works fine but it is copying the formulas and cell formatting not just the values. could anyone tell me how to obtain just the values?

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveQuick()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
  ws.[a2:o2000].ClearContents

sh.Range("B8", sh.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter 1, "MTU"
sh.Range("D9", sh.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
sh.Range("T9", sh.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
sh.[B8].AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Just assign the `.Value` of the source range to the `.Value` of the target range.

Comment: Or you could work with .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you.

```
sh.Range("D9", sh.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: This is great but the only problem is it is now pasting in row 1 where the headers are?

Comment: I am now only getting 1 row of data pasted in for some reason! any ideas?

Comment: @TrevorTurner - are you using the `Value` to `Value` method?

Comment: No the 'PasteSpecial' method. basically i have over 1000 rows that i need to copy selected data across (around 600 rows at present)

Comment: It is also ignoring the filter as everything that has a "No" in column T is being pasted in too :S

Comment: @TrevorTurner - I fixed the ignoring the filter problem with the `SpecialCells` method. As for the first issue, I tested this in a workbook of mine and it worked perfectly. Pasting the exact amount of rows that are copied. Are you sure you wrote the code into your module as I provided here.